# Implementation of pay-wall in .net MVC 4 application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to implement pay-wall mechanism in my MVC 4 application.
The requirement is to restrict access to some pages of a PDF file in preview mode and allow the complete file to display after pay-wall subscription.
i searched some links but they are providing only theoretical information about pay-wall.

Please suggest some link or examples for implementing it.
Any kind of help will be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Find a pdf lib that lets you split the document. Save the new document as another file. Have the newly created doc's URL and the full URL in your model. Then it's just a matter of auth to know which URL the user has access to.

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig You read my mind.

Comment: Thanks for your comment..i will try this...also suggest lib if you know any...

Comment: @AlexanderBrevig can you please suggest pdf viewer which i can ues in my application..

Comment: http://www.pdfsharp.com/PDFsharp/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=37&Itemid=48 take a look at this

Comment: thank you so much but i have a problem now i want custom pdf viewer to display pdf preview mode.